# Implicit declaration C

Tags: c

I wish to get my code cleaner, the code can compile, but unfortunately there are still some
stuff showing minor problem about this following "error message"

how can I solve this ?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

  int arr0[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
  int arr1[] = {2,2,2,2,2};
  int arr2[] = {1,4,2,4,4};


  int sizeArr0 = sizeof(arr0);
  int sizeArr1 = sizeof(arr1);
  int sizeArr2 = sizeof(arr2);

  parseArray(arr0[0], sizeArr0);
  parseArray(arr1[0], sizeArr1);
  parseArray(arr2[0], sizeArr2);

}


  int parseArray(int ch[], int sizeValue){

  int sum;
    for(int x = 0; x < ch; x++){
      int ch[x];

        if(x == 5){
        sum += 5;
        }

if (sum == 15){
      return sum;
        }
    }
  }
```

```
warning: implicit declaration of function ‘parseArray’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   17 |   parseArray(arr0[0], sizeArr0);
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~
test.c: In function ‘parseArray’:
test.c:30:22: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
   30 |     for(int x = 0; x < ch; x++){
```

Comment: `x` is an integer (`int`), `ch` is a pointer (`int []`) (pointing to the first index of an array), so comparing them makes no sense. Are you trying to iterate through all values of the int array?

Comment: Either move the definition of `main` below the definition of `parseArray`, or forward declare `parseArray` above `main` (and leave the definitions where they are). Also, `int ch[x];` in `parseArray` is shadowing the `ch` received as an argument (and then neither of them are used) which is serious code smell.

Comment: These are not really error messages but warnings. Still generally should be fixed as if they were errors really. Add a declaration `parseArray` function before it is called (at the beginning of the file). Change `x < ch` to `x < sizeValue`

Comment: Oh, `sizeof` will give you the size of the array in bytes, not number of elements.
Should be changed to `int sizeArr0 = sizeof(arr0)/sizeof(int);`.

Comment: there's also a mismatch in the first argument of `parseArray`. The function is expecting an `int` array but you're only passing it an `int`.

Comment: `parseArray` also doesn't return a value for all code paths. What if `sum != 15`, what should it return?

Comment: `sum` in `parseArray` is also uninitialized, so you have no idea what it's initial value will be, and doing `sum += ...` will result in an indeterminant value. You probably want to do `int sum = 0;`

Comment: Yeah, dont ask me why this value ch[] goes in it.
 Putting the code above the main() + the correction worked.
Thank. !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You need to have a function definition or prototype before the function which calls it

```
int parseArray(int ch[], size_t sizeValue);

int main()
{
    /* ... */
```

2. `for(int x = 0; x < ch; x++){` makes no sense and I believe that an typo.
   `for(size_t x = 0; x < sizeValue; x++){`
3. `int sizeArr0 = sizeof(arr0);` is giving you the size of the array in `char` not in element types. You need to divide it by the size of the elements. It should also have different type (`size_t`) `size_t sizeArr0 = sizeof(arr0) / sizeof(arr0[0]);`
4. All local function variables have to be initialized as they are **not** zeroed as global variables.  `int sum = 0;`
5. You pass the first element to the array not the reference to the  array   `parseArray(arr0, sizeArr0);` or   `parseArray(&arr0[0], sizeArr0);`

Comment: what does the "/" from this line of code mean ? 
size_t sizeArr0 = sizeof(arr0) / sizeof(arr0[0]);

Is there any good book who may explain these kind of stuff ? 

thank you !

Comment: @Adrien any C book